# Ruby test raise_if_conflictsのエラーについて

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Minitest実行のために下記のように`sample_test.rb`ファイルを作成しました。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class SampleTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_sample
    assert_equal 'RUBY', 'ruby'.upcase
  end
end
```

ここで`sample_test.rb`を実行すると

```
/Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2291:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate railties-5.1.3, because activesupport-5.1.2 conflicts with activesupport (= 5.1.3) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1411:in `activate' 
以下略
```

というエラーが確認され、Testに進めません。

`gem cleanup`と`gem uninstall activesupport -v "5.1.3"`を試してファイル実行しましたが結果変わらず手詰まりになっています。

ちなみにrubyのversionは`ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]`です。

ご意見頂きたくよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あまり根本的な解決策ではないですが、bundler経由で実行すれば依存関係の問題は解消するかもしれません。

```
gem install bundler
bundle init
```

```
# Edit Gemfile
gem 'minitest'
```

```
bundle install
bundle exec ruby sample_test.rb
```

「プロを目指す人のためのRuby入門」をお持ちなら、第12章のBundlerの説明も参照してください。

**2018.10.23追記**

この問題は新しいバージョンのRailsをインストールすることで解決するかもしれません。
詳しくは以下の記事をご覧ください。

[「プロを目指す人のためのRuby入門」でテスト失敗時に実行結果が正常に表示されない場合 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/1e928f8088b2cc6bd3fa)

Comment: 解決しました！

感動しました！！ありがとうございます！！！

Comment: よかったです。bundlerなしで実行できない問題は解決していないのですがw
ただ、Bundlerがなぜ必要になるのか、という必要性（本に書いた内容）については身をもってよく理解できたんじゃないかと思います。