# Minitestでのエラー

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

『プロを目指す人のためのRuby入門』に取り組んでいます。
「3-2 Minitestの基本」の箇所で、以下のようにテストコードを書いた`sample_test.rb`ファイルを作成しました。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class SampleTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_sample
    assert_equal 'RUBY', 'ruby'.upcase
  end
end
```

ここで`ruby smaple_test.rb`を実行すると、

.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2293:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate railties-5.1.4, because 
activesupport-5.1.6 conflicts with activesupport (= 5.1.4) 
(Gem::ConflictError)

というエラーが発生してしまいます。

このサイト上で既に同じような質問がされており（[Ruby test raise_if_conflictsのエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39962/ruby-test-raise-if-conflicts%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)）、著者さんがbundlerを用いた解決策を提案していたのでbundlerを試してみたのですが、`gem 'minitest'`の所で失敗してしまいます。

```
gem install bundler
→Fetching: bundler-1.16.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.6
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.6
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.6
Done installing documentation for bundler after 6 seconds
1 gem installed

bundle init
→Writing new Gemfile to /Users/****/Desktop/ruby-book/lib/Gemfile

gem 'minitest'
→ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
Unknown command minitest
```

ご回答、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

著者の伊藤です。「プロを目指す人のためのRuby入門」のご購入どうもありがとうございます。

さて、ご質問の件ですが、 [Ruby test raise_if_conflictsのエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39962/) の回答に書いた、

```
# Edit Gemfile
gem 'minitest'
```

の部分は、コメントの「Edit Gemfile（Gemfileを編集する）」にあるとおり、`bundle init`で生成されたGemfileを開いてその中身に`gem 'minitest'`を記述する、という意味です。

BundlerやGemfileについては本書の12.8.2項でも説明しているので、先にこちらに目を通しておくと良いかもしれません。

なお、この問題は新しいバージョンのRailsをインストールすることによっても解決します。
詳しくは以下の記事をご覧ください。

[「プロを目指す人のためのRuby入門」でテスト失敗時に実行結果が正常に表示されない場合 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/1e928f8088b2cc6bd3fa)

Comment: 早速ご回答ありがとうございます！！
https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/1e928f8088b2cc6bd3faの通り、railsの最新バージョンをダウンロードしたところ、解決致しました！
最近までrailsチュートリアルに取り組んでおり、そちらのバージョンに合わせていたので、railsが最新版では無かったのかもしれません。
大変助かりました。
ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです！こちらの記事を参照して「回答の承認」をお願いします。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers